# Duplicada com linguagens diferentes

Tags: suporte, perguntas-duplicadas

Fizeram essa pergunta [O que cada sinal significa nessa atribuição em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329703/o-que-cada-sinal-significa-nessa-atribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-c?noredirect=1#comment667686_329703)
. Eu sinalizei ela como possível duplicada das seguintes perguntas

- [O que significa esses operadores " > " e " ? "](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260901/o-que-significa-esses-operadores-e)
- [Como funciona este if/else com "?" e ":"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e/322979)
- [Dificuldade na Sintaxe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34200/dificuldade-na-sintaxe)

Porém me comentaram o seguinte: "não acredito que estas duas sejam duplicadas, uma é javascript a outra c++ e essa é C#"

Gostaria de saber nos casos em que, independente da linguagem, a resposta seria a mesma devemos marcar como duplicada?

Comment: Essa pessoa que colocou a dúvida na cabeça do @Barbetta foi eu. hahaha

Comment: O que caracteriza a duplicata é as respostas servirem plenamente para o que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não dá para usar isto sempre, mas este caso eu acho que acaba servido bem porque a sintaxe e semântica é idêntica. Como o Bacco comentou, o teste que deve fazer é se a(s) **resposta(s)** existentes respondem plenamente ao que foi perguntado. Em casos assim poderia ter comentado para deixar claro que apesar das linguagens serem diferentes funciona de forma idêntica, assim um usuário muito novato não fica na dúvida.

Adicionei [Diferenças entre If e operador ternário ?:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/101) por ser C# e dá mais detalhes. Sozinha acho que ela não seria suficiente. Também coloquei [É possível avaliar uma expressão ternária com 3 valores possíveis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272889/101) para algo avançado. Sempre é bom ter algo da própria linguagem.